# How do I check the file format of an usb stick?

Tags: mount, usb-drive

How can I check with what file-format an usb-stick was formatted?

(... in order to correctly mount it with `mount -t <fileformat> /dev/sdb1 /home/mountpoint`)

Thanks
vonSpotz

Comment: Try command "sudo blkid"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fdisk -l` to get info on all mounted disks

Comment: Hello Akhil,thanks for your answer!! For the USB-Stick of mine which is formatted with FAT32 it does show that under the column "type." In the column however of my usb-stick formatted in ext2 it only shows type: `Linux`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes up arrow in the shell and change the `vfat` to `ext2` in the mount command that just failed or vice versa. I would think you are not using dozens of file systems on those things so should be easy to narrow it down to your choices to use.